# why negative edge allowed in bellman ford algorithms?

Tags: algorithm, graph, dijkstra

why negative edges  cycles are allowed in bellman ford algorithms while no negative edge allowed in dijkstra algorithms?

Comment: You want to know why his algorithm can deal with negative edges while Dijkstra's can't?

Answer (score 6):

Allowed? Bellman-Ford algorithm allows *distinct edges* with negative weights (not supported in Dijkstra algorithm), but neither algorithm "allows" negative *cycles*. The shortest path problem makes no sense in presence of a negative cycle, so there's no meaningful way to "allow" negative cycles in any such algorithm.

Bellman-Ford algorithm can be made to detect the presence of a negative cycle and abort execution (abort, since no correct solution exists in that case).